# iOS 10: How to show incoming VOIP call notification when app is in background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, voip, usernotifications

I'm working on `audio/video call` and trying to get incoming call `notification` loop for 1 minute like WhatsApp shows in `iOS` when app is background, `Notification banner` hide and show with ringtone for 1 minute.

I have tried this code, it triggers only single time:

```
 UNMutableNotificationContent *content = [[UNMutableNotificationContent alloc] init];
    content.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Video Call from %@",userId];
    content.body = @"";
    content.userInfo = [userInfo mutableCopy];
    content.sound = [UNNotificationSound soundNamed:@""];

    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    now = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:3];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
    [calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitDay|NSCalendarUnitHour|NSCalendarUnitMinute|NSCalendarUnitSecond|NSCalendarUnitTimeZone fromDate:now];

    UNCalendarNotificationTrigger *trigger = [UNCalendarNotificationTrigger triggerWithDateMatchingComponents:components repeats:NO];
    UNNotificationRequest * request = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:@"INCOMING_VOIP_APN" content:content trigger:trigger];

    UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
    center.delegate = self;
    [center addNotificationRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"PUSHKIT : INCOMING_VOIP_APN");
        }
    }];
```

How can I achieve this? I'm using `UserNotifications.framework (iOS 10)` and `PushKit`.

Comment: You want a notification here for continuous 1 min or at 1 min interval?

Comment: i want notification to show for 3secs and hide and this process should be run only for 1 minute just like whatsapp incoming call when app is in background in ios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would suggest is that the local notification is only visible for that particular time. What you have to do is set a local notification or notification at the time of call. When the notification fires, in the delegate method of the notification you will have to build a custom logic with help of [NSTimer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449035/how-do-i-use-nstimer).

Create a view similar to push notification/ or view which you want to show for the call. Add it to the Application Window so it is shown on top of all views. After 3 sec remove this view and in the logic you can show the same view for 1 min.

Answer (score 2):

iOS 10 CallKit is much better, no more notification but system call UI, just like the native call. There are some sample codes at Github, which are easier to read than apple's Speakerbox sample.